# Targeting nodes dynamically with breadcrumbs

Tags: nodes, breadcrumbs

I'm using a 'resource' content type that can be browsed, searched, or accessed via a custom module. I'm also using the Custom breadcrumbs module.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to target [whichever] resource profile I user happens to have been viewing (dynamically since I won't know ahead of time which profile they're coming from)...and then target it in the breadcrumbs so that on pages accessed FROM the profiles (ie. a webform to give feedback on the profile for example)...a user can click the resource profile in the breadcrumb to go BACK to the profile they were viewing.

Anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like what you are looking to implement would require you to use [hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7) and then using `drupal_get_destination()` to give you the necessary URL parameter. The results from `drupal_get_destination()` will be compatible with the `l()` function and can be handled from the `hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()`.